# preventing cross-site scripting in wtrealm

Tags: c#, security, wif, adfs, ws-federation

We are creating a message like following which is a `SignInRequestMessage`

```
var message = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationMessage.CreateFromUri(Request.Url);
```

It has the following properties:

`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.SignInRequestMessage`

`Action: "wsignin1.0"`

`message.Parameters`

```
Count = 2
    [0]: {[wa, wsignin1.0]}
    [1]: {[wtrealm, javascript:alert(/test/)]}
```

Notice the second parameter in the message is a javascript, and when adfs redirect to it, we actually see the alert.

This happens when user is logged in, and within the same session we try to enter URL like following

```
https://localhost/StarterSTSLib/Login.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=javascript:alert(/test/)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how we prevent the `wtrealm` from this cross site scripting vulnerability?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't have adfs at hand and before I actually try it, I wonder what security issues can it introduce (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Production ready STS like ADFS does not rely on wtrealm to reply the token back. Whoever manages the ADFS will setup the app/relying party and specify the ednpoint where the token is posted to.

The STS generated by WIF "add sts reference" will take the wtrealm as the endpoint to post the token. That's why it is a development STS, not production ready.

In short on depends on the STS implementation wheter to use wtrealm as the endpoint. You should have a repository that asociates realms with urls like adfs.

Comment: We are using StarterSTS/IdentityServer implementation. Would you say this poses the same risk you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: identityserver supports specifying the endpoint per relying party in their admin console like adfs. They also support specifying wreply in the signin request (by turning on a configutation setting that is turned off by default) but not sure if they do something to avoid open redirects/cross site scripting.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is URL encoding.  Non-alphanumeric characters need to be replaced with their %xx (hex) representations...

https://example.com/StarterSTSLib/Login.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=javascript%3aalert%28%2ftest%2f%29